# More accurate time.sleep for short (millisecond) delays in Python 3?

Tags: python, delay, sleep

Consider this example:

```py
import sys,os
import time

sleep_time_ms = 1
numrepeats = 10

for sleep_time_ms in [1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500]:
  sleep_time_sec = sleep_time_ms/1000
  total_sleep_time_ms = numrepeats*sleep_time_ms
  total_sleep_time_sec = total_sleep_time_ms/1000
  print("sleep time {} ms ({} sec), numrepeats 10 -> expected total sleep time {} ms ({} sec)".format(sleep_time_ms, sleep_time_sec, total_sleep_time_ms, total_sleep_time_sec) )
  ts1 = time.time()
  for ix in range(numrepeats):
    time.sleep(sleep_time_sec)
  ts2 = time.time()
  print("  ... -> elapsed time {} sec".format(ts2-ts1))
```

Here are the results of Python 3.8.9 in MINGW64 `bash` shell of MSYS2 installation on Windows 10:

```
sleep time 1 ms (0.001 sec), numrepeats 10 -> expected total sleep time 10 ms (0.01 sec)
  ... -> elapsed time 0.15603327751159668 sec
sleep time 5 ms (0.005 sec), numrepeats 10 -> expected total sleep time 50 ms (0.05 sec)
  ... -> elapsed time 0.15575146675109863 sec
sleep time 10 ms (0.01 sec), numrepeats 10 -> expected total sleep time 100 ms (0.1 sec)
  ... -> elapsed time 0.15668964385986328 sec
sleep time 50 ms (0.05 sec), numrepeats 10 -> expected total sleep time 500 ms (0.5 sec)
  ... -> elapsed time 0.627091646194458 sec
sleep time 100 ms (0.1 sec), numrepeats 10 -> expected total sleep time 1000 ms (1.0 sec)
  ... -> elapsed time 1.09147310256958 sec
sleep time 500 ms (0.5 sec), numrepeats 10 -> expected total sleep time 5000 ms (5.0 sec)
  ... -> elapsed time 5.045071840286255 sec
```

... and for Python 3.7.3 in Anaconda on Windows 10:

```
sleep time 1 ms (0.001 sec), numrepeats 10 -> expected total sleep time 10 ms (0.01 sec)
  ... -> elapsed time 0.1423649787902832 sec
sleep time 5 ms (0.005 sec), numrepeats 10 -> expected total sleep time 50 ms (0.05 sec)
  ... -> elapsed time 0.15515851974487305 sec
sleep time 10 ms (0.01 sec), numrepeats 10 -> expected total sleep time 100 ms (0.1 sec)
  ... -> elapsed time 0.15677261352539062 sec
sleep time 50 ms (0.05 sec), numrepeats 10 -> expected total sleep time 500 ms (0.5 sec)
  ... -> elapsed time 0.6259005069732666 sec
sleep time 100 ms (0.1 sec), numrepeats 10 -> expected total sleep time 1000 ms (1.0 sec)
  ... -> elapsed time 1.088958978652954 sec
sleep time 500 ms (0.5 sec), numrepeats 10 -> expected total sleep time 5000 ms (5.0 sec)
  ... -> elapsed time 5.065780878067017 sec
```

So, there are large deviation of actual sleep time from the demanded sleep time, for low (millisecond) sleep times; first time its sort of close is at about 50 ms sleep time, then for larger sleep times it is OK. It actually seems that the system here hits a low threshold sleep time resolution at about 15 ms.

My question is - is there a way to get time.sleep to sleep more correctly for millisecond resolution - or lacking that, is there a method or a library I could use for more accurate sleep?

Comment: My counter-question is: Why do you need an accurate sleep? If you're trying to achieve something on Windows that's generally only achievable on a real-time OS, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Thanks @Sid - yes, that is it

Answer (score 1):

In terms of more accurate time have you considered using `datetime.datetime.now()`?

As I understand it `datetime` uses the system time, which is probably the best you'll get. You can then make a `timedelta` object and access the milliseconds on it.

```
  ts1 = datetime.datetime.now()
  time.sleep(sleep_time_sec)
  ts2 = datetime.datetime.now()
  delta = ts2 - ts1  # type: datetime.timedelta
```

EDIT: removed the first bit as I had misread the question